# How to implement multiple commands with root permissions with only one password prompt?

Tags: python, linux

I'm working on a GUI applications which calls two system commands respectively.

Those two commands require root permissions to be executed.

- The first approach I made, is to call `gksu <command_1>`, then `gksu <command_2>`.

  This works fine but the user must enter his password **twice** respectively, and I believe this is not good idea from a UX perspective.
- I tried to call `gksu` with the first command and `sudo` with the second, but I get this error:
  `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`
- So I tried to separate those command in a python file and call a command from the original file that looks like `gksu python3 commands.py`.

  I'm not sure whether this would be executed after I release a compiled version of the whole project, as I intend to use `pyinstaller --onefile` on it !

So, what I need exactly is to make the app be able to run a specific script with super user privileges considering the final state of the app which would be an executable-binary file and that **doesn't include** running the whole app with root permissions .

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with the GUI

Comment: please do not add SOLVED to the title of your question, instead mark your answer as correct in 2 days. review the [tour]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [Itz Wam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10902809/itz-wam), His answer guided me to the correct solution which is Using `pkexec` instead of `gksu` like this:

```
pkexec bash -c "command_1;command_2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could execute this :

```
gksu -- bash -c 'command1; command2; command3'
```

It will ask your password one time and execute the 3 commands as root

Source : https://askubuntu.com/questions/183608/gksudo-2-commands-with-one-pw-entry

Comment: Gives this output `Failed to execute child process “--” (No such file or directory)`